# Swift MapKit Unable to show location with Pin

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I am new to swift . I am trying to show user location with Pin . I added the permission in Info Plist to allow the user access . I am using the storyboard and I tried to edit the schema also added the default location but it did not fixed the problem . I am using CLLocationManagerDelegate with MapKit.

Here is my code for view controller ..

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!

    let manager  = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.first {
            manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

            render(location)
        }
    }
    func  render(_ location: CLLocation) {

        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)

        let span  = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1)

        let region  = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)

        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        let pin = MKPointAnnotation()
        pin.coordinate = coordinate
        mapView.addAnnotation(pin)

    }

}
```

Here is the screenshot of Info Plist
[image: Info Plist]

Here is the screenshot shot when I run the app..
[image: result]

Here is the code warning ..
[image: Need to run into main thread]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:
conform your ViewController class to CLLocationManagerDelegate and MKMapViewDelegate, declare your objects:

```
let mapView = MKMapView()
let manager = CLLocationManager()
```

in viewDidLoad present mapView and add constraints:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    mapView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(mapView)
    mapView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    mapView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    mapView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    mapView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

}
```

in viewDidAppear call requestAlwaysAuthorization and requestWhenInUseAuthorization and map configuration

```
manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    mapView.delegate = self
    mapView.mapType = .standard
    mapView.isZoomEnabled = true
    mapView.isScrollEnabled = true
    mapView.showsUserLocation = false // if you want to show default pin set to true

    if let coor = mapView.userLocation.location?.coordinate{
        mapView.setCenter(coor, animated: true)
    }
```

After that set didUpdateLocations

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations
    locations: [CLLocation]) {
    
    guard let mylocation = manager.location else { return }
    
    let myCoordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D = mylocation.coordinate

    mapView.mapType = MKMapType.standard

    let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: myCoordinates, span: span)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    // comment pin object if showsUserLocation = true
    let pin = MKPointAnnotation()
    pin.coordinate = myCoordinates
    pin.title = "You are here"
    mapView.addAnnotation(pin)
}
```

my info.plist Privacy authorizations

[image]

The result, I set Tokyo on my simulator options scheme

[image]

[image]

intere code with your DispatchQueue request in comments below:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

let mapView = MKMapView()
let manager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    mapView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(mapView)
    mapView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    mapView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    mapView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    mapView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.manager.delegate = self
            self.manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            self.manager.startUpdatingLocation()
            self.mapView.delegate = self
            self.mapView.mapType = .standard
            self.mapView.isZoomEnabled = true
            self.mapView.isScrollEnabled = true
            self.mapView.showsUserLocation = false // if you want to show default pin
        }
    }

    if let coor = mapView.userLocation.location?.coordinate {
        mapView.setCenter(coor, animated: true)
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations
    locations: [CLLocation]) {
    
    guard let mylocation = manager.location else { return }
    
    let myCoordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D = mylocation.coordinate

    mapView.mapType = MKMapType.standard

    let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: myCoordinates, span: span)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    
    let pin = MKPointAnnotation()
    pin.coordinate = myCoordinates
    pin.title = "You are here"
    mapView.addAnnotation(pin)
 }
}
```

Comment: Sorry small error .. I tried to run this line code into main thread ..

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
                self.manager.delegate = self
                self.manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
                self.manager.startUpdatingLocation()
            }
        }

Comment: but still same warning .. This method can cause UI unresponsiveness if invoked on the main thread. Instead, consider waiting for the `-locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization:` callback and checking `authorizationStatus` first.

Comment: @Mohammad I don't Know why but simply remove if statement and put all manger attributes into DispatchQueue method: DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.manager.delegate = self
            self.manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            self.manager.startUpdatingLocation()
            self.mapView.delegate = self
            .... ecc. ecc.
  
        } .... please check that is the right answer

Comment: do we needs to check CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() ?

Comment: Put DispatchQueue Method into if statement -> if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.manager.delegate = self
                self.manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest ......

Comment: Still same warning .. if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.manager.delegate = self
                    self.manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
                    self.manager.startUpdatingLocation()
                }

            }

Comment: Let me add the add the screenshot

Comment: I added the screenshot .. Thanks

Comment: Are you using storyboard ?

Comment: No only code, I set constraints and present map view with my extension which I deleted as it wouldn't help you....

Comment: I am using storyboard and added the Map kit . Technically Any UI update should into main thread which we are saying to do it .. Is it possible to share the complete code you are using please ?..I want to learn why it compelling ..

Comment: I update my answer with programmatically constraints In viewDidLoad now you have intere code... Please check that is the right answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249669/discussion-between-mohammad-and-fabio).

Comment: I really do not know why I am receiving waring but i follow same things as you mentioned .  Thanks .. May be any update made on this function ..

Comment: I update my answer with intere code, copy and paste in a new project and try, firstable activate info.plist Privacy authorizations...

Comment: Everything is correct .. as you mentioned  and working fine...Problem is this function CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(). Compelling This method can cause UI unresponsiveness if invoked on the main thread. Instead, consider waiting for the `-locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization:` callback and checking `authorizationStatus` first...

Comment: Have activate Privacy - Location Always Usage Description and Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description in info.plist? There's a screenshot above

Comment: yes . I did.. ..

Comment: I don't know why.... Because I haven't warning on my Xcode...

Comment: Thanks .. for help .. I posted new questions on this matter .. because in enterprise development it will be questionable ...

Comment: @Mohammad I answer you in your new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you haven't added location permission description in your info.plist. That why xcode showing you => Error: This method can cause UI unresponsiveness if invoked on the main thread.

In your info.plist file add this:

<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
```